# How can I get Eclipse to Prompt about continuing launch if dependencies of the project contain errors?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, ide, tdd

In Eclipse, if I want to run an opened project using one of the *Run configurations* (e.g. a Junit test runner), Eclipse will prompt me if the project contains errors. The option is in (*Run/Debug* -> *Launching* -> *Continue Launch if project contains errors*). That's fine.

Now, assume I have a project Child depending on Parent, and both projects are open in Eclipse. In my case, Child is a bunch of unit tests for Parent — which might be a suboptimal (but immutable) setup.

If I change something innocuous in Parent, then run Child's tests, Eclipse **rebuilds** Parent, and then runs the tests of Child on a fresh Parent, which is OK.

If I now change something in Parent *that creates an error*. and prevents Eclipse from rebuilding it, Eclipse will run Child's tests based on the **latest succesful build** of Parent. So I **silently** get test results for a prior version of the Parent project.

This is very confusing because the Error markers will appear late (along Parent's rebuild) and I may not even be looking at them

Is there a way to tell Eclipse to warn me if it didn't manage to rebuild the dependent projects, *for which it already has the policy to update the build anyway* ?

Comment: Surely it already does this? It should say "Errors exist in required projects: [Parent]. Proceed with launch?" How are you configuring Child to be "depending on" Parent?

Comment: Eclipse creates the .class file(s) even if there are errors in the project. It doesn't keep a 'history' of the .class files - are you sure it's not this? For more info, see http://randomallsorts.blogspot.ch/2012/01/generating-bytecode-with-errors-in.html